# Can't connect to SQL Server from elixir/phoenix in Docker

Tags: docker, odbc, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to connect a "Phoenix (Elixir)-Application" (packed as Docker-Container) to `microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest Docker-Container`

Therefore I'm using https://hex.pm/packages/mssql_ecto as Adapter

```
use Mix.Config

config :my_api, MyApi.Repo,
adapter: MssqlEcto,
database: "dev",
username: "sa",
password: "my_api_password",
hostname: "127.0.0.1",
#odbc_driver: "{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}",
#odbc_driver: "{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}",
#odbc_driver: "{ODBC Driver 13.1 for SQL Server}",
#odbc_driver: "{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}",    # <- Default
#port: "1433" # <- Default
```

My current Dockerfile for running the phoenix-Application in Docker:

```
FROM elixir:1.5.2

# install ODBC driver
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https debconf-utils apt-utils
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/8/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
RUN apt-get install -y erlang-odbc
```

I guess the problem is located in my Dockerfile, especially the lines for installing the ODBC driver. When you look at my Mix.Config, you see that i tried many combinations of "odbc-driver"-strings - not one of them works..

heres the output of the phoenix start:

```
** (Mix) The database for MyApi.Repo couldn't be created: %Mssqlex.Error{constraint_violations: [], message: "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0' : file not found Connection to database failed. | ODBC_CODE 01000 | SQL_SERVER_CODE 0", odbc_code: "01000"}
```

Is anybody out there whos got a working Elixir (docker-image) with the possibility to connect to "microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest Docker-Container"?

Im very thankful for any help!

BTW ... im able to connect to the "mssql-server-linux Container" from Host via HeidiSQL and
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17 => so no problems with "mssql-server-linux Container" at all.

Setup:

- HOST OS: Windows 10 Pro
- Docker for Windows: 17.12.0-ce-win47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all struggling with this: here are the relevant lines of my working Dockerfile for Ubuntu 16:

```
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install apt-utils apt-transport-https wget
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/mssql-ubuntu-xenial-release/ xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssqlpreview.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN env ACCEPT_EULA=Y DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    cpanminus \
    msodbcsql \
    unixodbc-dev-utf16
RUN apt-get install unixodbc-dev-utf16
RUN cd /root && \
    wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MJ/MJEVANS/DBD-ODBC-1.56.tar.gz && \
    tar xf DBD-ODBC-1.56.tar.gz && \
    cd /root/DBD-ODBC-1.56      && \
    perl Makefile.PL -u         && \
    cpanm --installdeps .       && \
    make                        && \
    make test                   && \
    make install                && \
    rm -rf /root/DBD-ODBC-1.56.tar.gz /root/DBD-ODBC-1.56

# Set locale
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

The last lines are important for the ODBC-Driver to work properly.

```
odbc_driver: "{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}
```

for a working MssqlEcto-Configuration!

@Nolan: i was very happy when i get it working with Ubuntu, i switched instantly to Debian (elixir 1.6) - it works. but u have to change some parts. Heres my working Dockerfile for elixir.1.6 (debian) - let me if it works with 1.6.1

BTW: the odbc driver is very bitchy when is comes to wrong locale configuration ;)

```
FROM elixir:1.6
ENV REFRESHED_AT 29-01-2018


# install odbc driver
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install apt-utils apt-transport-https wget
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/8/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN env ACCEPT_EULA=Y DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
     build-essential \
     cpanminus \
     msodbcsql \
     unixodbc-dev
RUN apt-get install unixodbc-dev
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools
RUN cd /root && \
    wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MJ/MJEVANS/DBD-ODBC-1.56.tar.gz && \
    tar xf DBD-ODBC-1.56.tar.gz && \
    cd /root/DBD-ODBC-1.56      && \
    perl Makefile.PL -u         && \
    cpanm --installdeps .       && \
    make                        && \
    make test                   && \
    make install                && \
    rm -rf /root/DBD-ODBC-1.56.tar.gz /root/DBD-ODBC-1.56

# set locale configuration
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && \
    update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

# install hex
RUN mix local.hex --force

# install rebar
RUN mix local.rebar --force

# install phoenix
RUN mix archive.install https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez --force

# install node
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
RUN bash nodesource_setup.sh
RUN apt-get install nodejs
```

IDK if this is production ready (in sense of security and optimizing) - when u get an optimized version please let me know! cheers

Comment: Just hit this myself. Mind sharing the bits of your Dockerfile that get you from Ubuntu 16.04 to running Elixir? This doesn't work with elixir:1.6.1, probably because it's based on Debian 8. Thanks! Also, any idea which bits of the above actually resolve the problem, for when I'd like to deploy to prod but don't want a huge image?

Comment: Hi @Nolan, just look at the answer now

Comment: FYI the size of the image (Debian) is 445 MB